# IE not showing negative margin when using filter for transparancy

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transparency

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cuMZA/4/

This works flawlessly in Chrome, Firefox. But in IE this fails to show the red block. It seems it's using: overflow:hidden as setting.

However I must use the gradient option to show a semitransparant background in the outer div. What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I added the `position: absolute;` property to the #block div and it seems to work this way. Don't know why this overflow:hidden behavior coming from the filters. I also tried adding `overflow: visible;` but didn't work.